# SQL same text columns in rows but they are not duplicate

Tags: sql, merge, duplicates, string-comparison

[image]

Here is my question: I have a SQL table called `translation`. And for simplicity, we got three columns `id`, `ENG` and `FR`. `id` is the primary key. In the database, I noticed two records with the same `ENG` text value "First Name". I removed all trailing spaces using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` but when I did

```
SELECT ENG, COUNT(*) 
FROM translation 
GROUP BY ENG 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

it returned zero records. Also, when I do

```
select * 
from translation 
where ENG = "First Name"
```

I only get one record returned, instead of two. My task was to remove duplicate records and clearly those two should be merged together. So I was wondering is there a way to compare text fields and spot the differences OR is there a way to merge all text fields with some LETTERS into one because I don't want to do update statement for all cases like this. Thanks in advance!

Note: columns look a bit different but there's my point

Comment: Please tag with database platform, and show sample data and expected output.

Comment: Do they have differing numbers of spaces between "First" and "Last" or one tabs vs spaces, etc?

Comment: okay I will post the sample

Comment: From what I can see, they both have one white space in between the word and I've already removed extra spaces at the beginning and end of word

Comment: i don't see any duplicates from your example.. you might want to help us out

Comment: id 202 and 62 have the exact ENG text fields "Internal name" and when I did "select * from translation where ENG = 'Internal name', it only gave me one record. I dont really care about id and updated on(the third field) cuz all I want is to list all the UNIQUE English text so that they can be translated into French later. But right now I have duplicate entries with the exact eng text. Hope that helps.

Comment: I will do stuff in my php code later on to make sure i only insert the entries with unique eng text field. Right now I am just trying to clean up my DB so that all existing rows should have unique eng text field.

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?